# Find where one function is greater than another

Tags: functions

$f: y=x^3, g: y=5$

Here's what I did:

$$f(x) - g(x) = x^3 - 5 = (x - \sqrt[3]{5})(x^2 + x\sqrt[3]{5} + \sqrt[3]{25}).$$

How can I prove that the second factor of the multiplication is positive?
***It is not a, but 3***

Comment: $x^2 \geqslant 0$ for all real number $x$.

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal True, but $x\sqrt[3]{5}$ is not...

Comment: @5xum: Yes, but the $x$ was added after I commented.

Comment: The quadratic has complex roots and hence is positive for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that $h(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ is always positive by showing that the discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$ is *negative* (thus showing that $h$ has no real roots) and $a>0$ (thus showing that $h$ is positive for large $x$).

The two points together prove that, since $h$ is continuous, $h$ must be positive everywhere on $\mathbb R$.

---

That said, you are **way** overcomplicating the answer.

You can solve it much simpler. Since $z\mapsto z^3$ is a monotone funciton, you know that $x<y$ if and only if $x^3 < y^3$, meaning that $x<\sqrt[3]{5}$ if and only if $x^3<5$ and you are done.